# Which school is the school that Claude Debussy studied in?

Tags: history

I am confused about the school that Debussy studied in. I searched on wiki it said Debussy studied in CNSMDP. But in the other website it said Debussy studied in school located in 14 Rue de Madrid, which is the address of CRR de Paris. So which one is the school that Debussy studied in?

Comment: maybe this is more for musicfans.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I agree @topomorto. This seems to be more a question about "facts" than about music history.

Answer (score 1):

He began studies at Paris Conservatory when he was 10 years old (1872) where he studied for 11 years. He then won a composition competition (Prix de Rome) for his cantata L'Enfant Prodigal (The Prodigal Child) which financed 3 more years of study in Rome, but he only studied  in Rome for 2 years before returning to Paris.